# wordpress: How to Change innerHTML of Dynamically Generated divs using JS? Error: 'cannot set property innerHTMl of null'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to change the innerHTML of a "View cart" button with a dynamically generated div class on Wordpress/Woocommerce. I asked a previous question about this and was suggested (thank you Mike :) ) that because JS is an onload event, the class only changes after the user clicks an "add to cart" button so the js never runs in time.

**I need to know how to change the innerHTML of the "view cart" button *before* anyone sees it. I would like to change the words "view cart"--->"view cats".**

Here is my site: http://woocommerce-8778-19565-47619.cloudwaysapps.com/product-category/jewelry#. Please click "add to cart" and see "View cart" button appear.

I wrote some very basic JS:

```
   1. window.onload = function viewcart(){
   2.   document.querySelectorAll('.added_to_cart').innerHTML="view cats";
   3.  //  document.querySelector('a.added_to_cart.wc-forward:before').innerHTML="view cats";
   4. //  document.getElementsByClassName('.wc-forward::after').innerHTML="view cats";
   5. }
```

3-4 are examples of some ways I tried to solve the issue.

**SOMETIMES** the 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null' message appears, but **SOMETIMES** it does not. **Element Inspector shows the JS is loading though!**

**What I did in order (step 1, step 2, step 3):**
1. Loaded the js to my Wordpress (**using CHILD theme**) by adding the external js sheet (viewcart.js) to the child theme file w/STFP.

2. Added the following to CHILD theme's functions.php:

   ```
   <?php
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_add_scripts' );
   function child_add_scripts() {
   wp_register_script(
   'viewcartscript',
   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/viewcart.js',
   true,
   false
   );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'viewcartscript' );
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. Tried changing true to false and removing one of the "true"/"false" from the php function.

I will choose best answer more quickly than last question (2 days ago). Thank you in advance for ANY help. You guys are truly the best xo :)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.added_to_cart')` will return an "array" of matching elements. You need to loop over that and set each `.innerHTML`. Or if you expect only one, just use `document.querySelector('.added_to_cart')` which will return the first found, or null.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thank you so much for your reply :) Sorry I did not mention, but I already tried document.querySelector without 'All'. Unfortunately the first 'view cart' does not get edited by the js even then. So I dont know if loop will help.

Answer (score 0):

`Document.querySelectorAll('button.added_to_cart')` returns a list (nodelist) of the selectors in the document, that match `'.added_to_cart'`. As Ian said, the best way would be to loop this list  and change their element's inner html one by one.
CSS Pseudo-classes will never return any elements.

Edited:
You could also use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('added_to_cart');
for ( var i=0; i < elements.length; i++)
   elements[i].innerHtml = 'view cats';
```

Comment: My problem is I tried using `document.querySelector` and checked just the first button, but it didn't even apply to the first button. I really wonder if a loop will work then, although of course I will still try it. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You could also use var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('added_to_cart'); For ( var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) elements[i].innerHtml = 'view cats';

Comment: Hello again Pastel Belem, thank you for your suggestion again. I tried your suggestion as well as this: `var a = document.querySelectorAll('.added_to_cart.wc-forward');
for (var a=0; a<300; a++){                
a.innerHTML="#";
}` and some variations of both of our code. Unfortunately, I still cannot get it to work. Could it be my before:: after:: css is causing disruptions? Should I try editing the core php or using php loop in functions.php? Sorry for all of the questions. Thank you again!

Comment: By the way, is that egg tart in your photo? It looks so delicious!